# ChartJS animate only one dataset

Tags: chart.js

I’m using donut chartjs graph to simulate a circle progress bar, with 40 positions in the dataset with green and 60 positions with light gray (simulating a 40% progress bar).
But when I start the graph, all datasets animate, but I would like to keep the gray ones static and animate only the green ones, to simulate a progress bar. Is this possible?

PS: I didn’t use other progress bar lib because I need the stripped effect that I have with 100 positions in my dataset.

Suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39087208/3376838) is similar to yours, there are two approaches, or you set up a `plugin` and draw a circle under the chart or draw two charts one of them is the background with no animation them set both to position `absolute`.